# I am trying to navigate to multiple activities using intents and i am getting a run time exception, I am a beginner with eclipse , so please guide me

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText txtUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
         String username = txtUserName.getText().toString();
         String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
         String foo = new String("131031001");
         String foo2 = new String("131031002");
         String foo3 = new String("131031003");
         String foo4 = new String("131031004");
         String foo5 = new String("131031005");
         try{
           if(username.length() > 0 && password.length() >0) {
             DBUserAdapter dbUser = new DBUserAdapter(MainActivity.this);
             dbUser.open();
             dbUser.AddUser();
             if(dbUser.Login(username, password))
             {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(username.equals(foo))
                {
                   Intent nextActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                   nextActivity2.putExtra("Second",username);
                   startActivity(nextActivity2);
                }
                else if(username.equals(foo2)) {
                   Intent nextActivity3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ThirdActivity.class);
                    nextActivity3.putExtra("Third",username);
                    startActivity(nextActivity3);
                }
                else if(username.equals(foo3))
                {
                   Intent nextActivity4 = new Intent(getBaseContext(),FourthActivity.class);
                   nextActivity4.putExtra("Fourth",username);
                   startActivity(nextActivity4);
                }
                else if(username.equals(foo4)) {
                   Intent nextActivity5 = new Intent(getBaseContext(),FifthActivity.class);
                   nextActivity5.putExtra("Fifth",username);
                   startActivity(nextActivity5);
                }
                else if(username.equals(foo5)) {
                   Intent nextActivity6 = new Intent(getBaseContext(),SixthActivity.class);
                   nextActivity6.putExtra("Sixth",username);
                   startActivity(nextActivity6);
                }
                else {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Result does not exist! Try later!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            dbUser.close();
          }

        }catch(Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }

    });

    Button btreg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btreg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class);
          startActivity(nextActivity);
       }
     });
   }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
   }
}
```

All other activities are coded similar to the above. 
Here is my logcat.

```
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): Process: com.skcetresults, PID: 1196
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{com.skcetresults/com.skcetresults.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.skcetresults.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:15)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
10-28 14:53:10.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     ... 11 more
```

With just two intents the code worked fine, but when I'm comparing the value with strings, the app crashes, I don't know where the bug is.

Comment: Put **Intent intent = getIntent();** inside onCreate() method. And what is the line number 15 in SecondActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getBaseContext() and getApplicationContext(), use MainActivity.this as context, will work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it like this

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

Intent i = getIntent();

}
```

}

If the extra data are strings you can get it like this:

```
String nameString = i.getStringExtra("nameExtra");
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use getIntent() before onCreate()**, there's simply no Intent available at that point.

In your code, I suspect that you are trying to get `StringExtras from Intent`, But as intent is null, it is throwing `NullPointerException`.

In your `Second Activity` you can use `getIntent()` in `onCreate()` method.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  
    Intent intent;   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        intent = getIntent();
        String userName = intent.getStringExtra("Second");
        ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use little pieces of code checking, to ensure your intent behaves properly. For example, you could surround your `getIntent` code with an `if` statement. For which proper method to call, you have to wander around a bit, as this depends on what you want your app to do. Fortunately, Eclipse delivers you all the related documentation, when you write down some piece of Android resources, e.g. `Intent`.